# PHP - a little more than how to combine two images while keeping transparency

Tags: php, transparency, gd

So I already know how to combine two images and keep transparency using the GD image library with php however I need to be able to pull images from the server while keeping the dimensions in the power of two so that I can use them as textures to be applied to 3d objects in opengl.

So my real question is how can I place a scaled version of an image that keeps its original proportions within a transparent one that has a 256x256 or 128x128 dimension. Also Id like to place the resized image within the center of the completely transparent one.

Some help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this references, I think it's what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Comment: That part I have already but Im using a loop where I go over every pixel to make sure it retains its proper color and transparency because sometimes using that method alone you get blank spots where your image is black. What I need now is how do I place my one image in a certain spot within another